# Extract Version Number from String and Filter By Min Version

Tags: sql, type-conversion, postgresql-9.6

I have a database table which includes a user agent string. This user agent includes information like device type, browser type and most importantly a version number. Most examples look like this

```
App Name/4.0.0 (iPad; iOS 12.3.1; Scale/2.00)
App Name/4.14.3 (iPad; iOS 14.0.1; Scale/2.00)
App Name/5.15.2 (iPad; iOS 10.3.3; Scale/2.00)
```

and the information I'd like to extract is "4.0.0." Specifically I'd like to grab a list of all entries that have a min version of 4.0.0

Here's what I've got so far

```
WHERE TRIM(SUBSTRING(user_agent,19,6))
```

which encouragely returns 4.0.0, 4.14.3, and 5.15.2. However it's a string, not an int so I'm not sure how to find a min version.

- Is there a better way to extract that version number than my use of substring?
- How do you sort by or filter by a version number?

Comment: It can't be an int. Ints don't have any decimal points, and floating point values only have one. It's a string that represents the various parts of a version number, so you'll have to extract the individual parts, convert them to integers, and then compare the different parts to find which is the greatest. Otherwise, you can just `ORDER BY version` and use a `TOP 1` in your `SELECT`, which would get you the minimum as a string value (which may not always work the way you'd expect).

Comment: Also, when using the SQL tag, it's almost always necessary to also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as syntax and functionality varies between them. You can read this as a suggestion if you hover your mouse pointer over the SQL tag at the bottom left of your post and read the pop-up tag description.

Comment: Just realized I didn't address your actual question, which was *a better way to extract that version number*. The answer to that would depend on the specific DBMS you're using, which you didn't provide a tag for, so it would be difficult to answer.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.